# "jfrog rt set-props" prepends key with semi-colon

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

example using jfrog cli 1.14.0:

```
jfrog rt set-props repo/artifact.zip this=that
```

this results in:
Property: `;this`

Value: `that`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi Sam,
Welcome to StackOverflow, you should probably give a bit more context regarding your question.
So everybody can understand better, and try to help you out.

Comment: I tried to keep the repo-steps as crisp as possible - not sure what else is needed here. Are others able to use `set-props` this way without issue?

Comment: This is a known issue. 
You can track the fix progress [here](https://github.com/JFrogDev/jfrog-cli-go/issues/135).